# offline location picker in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, location, jquery-location-picker

I want to write a reactjs component to get the location from user ... I wanna use map and location picker on map. I just need to save `latitude` and `longitude` in my variables When the user choose her location on the map.

How can I do that?
I tried [react-leaflet-location-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-location-picker) and [react-location-picker](https://github.com/rameshsyn/react-location-picker) but these are online. I need an `Offline location picker`

(I am using reactjs and Ant Design)